# What are the tools for byte code level scrambling in Android

Tags: android, apk

I was looking for some bytecode level scrambling tool for Android application.

I have already applied Proguard for source code level scrambling and expecting something beyond that.

I have heard about byte code level scrambling but couldn't find any tool related to that.

Please mention if someone knows some examples.

Answer (score 0):

For the byte code level scrambling, following application can be used. But most of them are not recommended for production level.

> APKFuscator - https://github.com/strazzere/APKfuscator - Developer's
>   recommendation is "should not be relied upon for production
>   environments"
>
> dalvik-obfuscator - https://github.com/thuxnder/dalvik-obfuscator -
>   Developer's recommendation is "WARNING: Don't apply this technique to
>   your applications. It can break your app. It is for research only!"
>
> DexGuard - https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/dexguard - A
>   commercial product.

Ref:- https://www.cryptolux.org/images/9/94/Alexandrina-thesis.pdf